# How to attach a file to the post url in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, attachment

I am developing a Helpdesk application, in this app I am able to read and reply for the tickets sent by the customer. Now I got a requirement, I have to upload a file also. I have a post url to reply for the ticket, I will use Namevaluepairs to attach message with the url..

```
nameValuepair("id",ticketId);(nameValuepair is the instance of BasicNameValuePair)
nameValuepair("subject",subject);
nameValuepair("reply",message);
```

If file is not there then it will be like the above code. If file is there I one more parameter comes for file. What I have to do is to attach a file and encode it and then include it into Namevaluepair...

```
nameValuepair("file",encodedfile);
```

How can I Upload the file to this app and encode it.
I got some resources to attach a file to the default android email client using email intent, that was not helpful  for me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uploading a file is more complicated than adding a name-value pair. You need to get the output stream of the request and write the file. You can find an example [**here**](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Http client by Apache and its POST method:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = appContext.GetHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your.url.com");
httppost.setEntity(new FileEntity(yourFile, PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
InputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know this, but I want to know how to attach file with the post url